# BadImageException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine' or one of its dependencies.'

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

After updating Visual Studio 2017 to 15.5, I'm no longer able to debug my unit tests (I can run the tests fine, and I can debug non-test programs).

I keep getting the following exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'VSTestVideoRecorder' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'VSTestVideoRecorder' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.dll
FrameworkName cannot have less than two components or more than three components.
```

I've confirmed that each project is consistently using the same compiler setting (7+ w/ minor versions), and are all targeting .Net 4.7.  Except for updating VS to 15.5, the code in some of the files at issue have not changed at all.

I haven't found anything helpful about these exceptions or about how to address them.  It certainly seems like something caused by the VS update.

Any ideas?  Is reinstalling VS the only solution?

Comment: Presumably related bug entry is 'Fixed - pending release' https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168116/badimageformatexception-microstvisualstudioquality.html

Answer (score 0):

Just got same issue.

I start search around for solutions and after doing some things, somehow, the problem got fixed.
What I have done was:

- Deleted all my %temp% folder ([insane hum?](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/324#issuecomment-350067409))
- Commented all my bindingRedirect and test solution app.config (i
  needed)
- Deleted the content of my packages folder
- Updated my Visual Studio 2017 to latest version  (15.5.2)

Don't know witch step make it work (or combination of steps). Made lots of tries.

And voilà, it worked.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  The app.config in my test project was pretty bare-bones, with just EF stuff.  Deleting the %temp% folder did not resolve the exceptions.  I've seen mention of this issue elsewhere, so hopefully your suggestion helps someone.

Comment: Sad to hear. I also deleted my packages folder. Try that. Updated the answer. Also try clean all solution and rebuild it again.

Comment: I'm at 15.5.2, and deleting the packages folder did not help, unfortunately.  Thank you, though; I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: I have read you question more careful, and noted that you have this error: "FrameworkName cannot have less than two components or more than three components". I think this your you real problem. I've seach google and found this: https://github.com/akoeplinger/dnx-globbing-loop/blob/master/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Runtime.Versioning/FrameworkName.cs (that throws your error) and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414023(v=vs.110).aspx (see ArgumentException). Are you using anything of this?

Comment: Nope, not using either of those.  I can replicate the issue if I make a new test project too with nothing but a single test that just prints a counter to the console.  It's my understanding that this is a bug in VS 15.5+.